# VB.Net - Selenium can't find a javascript function on the page I want to run

Tags: javascript, vb.net, selenium

I am trying to make some automation software automating Chrome. I can navigate to the page, and the page has a button declared like this in the code:

```
<div class="bn_diff_image">
   <a href="javascript:setMode('ImageText', 0);"></a>
</div>
```

The class shows an image of a button. I need to click that button (to execute the javascript) but I can't get it to work. Here is the code I have tried:

```
chromeDriver.ExecuteJavaScript("javascript:setMode('ImageText', 0)")
```

This returns an error that setMode cannot be found. I put a Thread.Sleep in the code to ensure the page was fully loaded before calling this, it made no difference

I tried accessing the button via CSS selector

```
chromeDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[href*=\'ImageText', 0']")).Click()
```

It can't find the selector and fails

I tried finding the div by classname and clicking on that

```
chromeDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("bn_diff_image")).Click()
    '
```

but it fails saying it can't find the element

How in the world can I click on this link or run that javacript on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this css selector :

```
div.bn_diff_image a[href^='javascript:setMode']
```

use it like this :

```
chromeDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.bn_diff_image a[href^='javascript:setMode']")).Click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind, I am bad at this, The element  was in an iFrame. Once I elected the Frame it worked

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.